# How to call a logging function from a generic utility plugin from another plguin

Tags: plugins, functions, logging

I want to add some logging to my plugin, and for various reason want to create my own wrapper function around error_log(). And for reusability, I'd like to stick my wrapper function in a separate utility plugin.

Assuming that I have the utility plugin, and the my_error_log() function is there, how can I call it from anywhere in my other plugins? How can I be sure I *can* call it? Are plugins functions available across my WordPress code? Should I somehow ensure that my utility plugin is loaded first?

As I understand them, I don't think I can use a hook or action, as I want to call the error logging function from inside the code of my other plugins, for debugging purposes, as that code executes.

PS: Yes, I do realize this is rather a n00b question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assuming that I have the utility plugin, and the my_error_log() function is there, how can I call it from anywhere in my other plugins?

By calling it, there are no special steps

> How can I be sure I can call it? Are plugins functions available across my WordPress code?

Yes, plugins are not sandboxed, everything is loaded into the same melting pot. WordPress is aware a plugin exists but it doesn't track/tag/sandbox code inside plugins. It's just a mechanism for loading arbitrary PHP.

> Should I somehow ensure that my utility plugin is loaded first?

Yes, you should test if the functions/classes exist. How you would do that though is generic PHP that has nothing to do with WordPress though, e.g. `if ( function_exists(... etc`

Comment: Thanks Tom, that's very helpful!